# Is transiting in Japan still possible?

Tags: transit, japan, covid-19

Does the new covid restrictions that Japan has introduced effect does who are planning to transit through Japan? The flight I plan to book from Singapore to Toronto stops at NRT.

https://www.mofa.go.jp/ca/fna/page4e_001053.html

> For the time being, foreign nationals who have stayed in any of the following 159 countries/regions within 14 days prior to the application for landing are denied to enter Japan in pursuant to the Article 5, paragraph (1), item (xiv) of Immigration Control and Refugee Recognition Act, unless special exceptional circumstances are found. Note that foreigners (from the countries and regions where the entry bans do not apply) are not denied to enter Japan even when they arrive in Japan via those countries or regions, which are subject to denial of permission to entry, for refueling or transit purpose. Those who entered those countries or regions will, however, be subject to the entry ban.

I believe according to this transit is fine.

Comment: Can you clarify which flight(s) are involved, and whether they were booked as a single ticket or not? I would think that transit is fine as long as you can stay airside (booked on a single ticket, checked through to the final destination, no airport change, no overnight stay...) as you would not need to "enter Japan".

Comment: It's a single booking on united.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transit is still allowed, according to https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> Japan:

> 2. Effective 30 November 2021 until 31 December 2021, passengers are not allowed to enter.
>
>    - This does not apply to:
>    - nationals of Japan;
>    - passengers with a visa issued by Japan outside Japan.

Note that from what I recall Japan never closed international transit for air travelers because of COVID-19 (unlike e.g. Taiwan), as long as the transit doesn't entail entering Japan.

Comment: Note however that in such situations, it is highly likely that many flights will be cancelled due to a drop in demand. Make sure you are up to date with the status of the flights.

Comment: @jcaron true, though I believe Japan already wasn't that open anyway.